# Not all Views inside ViewPager's Fragments will update

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, togglebutton

I have 3 Fragments inside my ViewPager.
Inside my Fragments I added static ToggleButtons.*(static, because I didn't find a workaround for a nullpointerexception, if I wanted to use findViewById() inside my Fragment classes in custom methods and not in onCreateView() )*

Outside the ViewPager in my MainActivity I have a Reset-Button, that should reset all ToggleButtons (on all 3 Fragments) to "unchecked".

Every time i click on the Reset-Button, only the current Page and every neighbor-page gets updated.

E.G.

- Current Page : 0 Updated Pages: 0,1
- Current Page : 1 Updated Pages: 0,1,2
- Current Page : 2 Updated Pages: 1,2

I think the Problem is the FragmentPagerAdapter. The [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) says :

> Implementation of PagerAdapter that represents each page as a Fragment
>   that is persistently kept in the fragment manager **as long as the user
>   can return to the page**.

When I'm on Page 2 i can not directly return to Page 0 , so I think the Views from Page 0 (= Fragment 0 ) are not in memory anymore?!
**So how can I access the ToggleButtons inside a Fragment that is not visible at the moment nor is a neighbor of the current Fragment ? Is there any workaround?**

### EDIT:

I found out, that in deed all checked()-values of my ToggleButtons (on ALL Fragments) get updated, but not the inflated Views of Fragments, that are not visible and not neighbor Fragments. So when I return to those previous Fragments, the checked()-values of the ToggleButtons are reset to the state last time the fragment was visible. strange...

Example:

1. Page2 active - ToggleButton_Page2.checked() = true
2. switch to Page 0
3. press Reset-Button. Toast ToggleButton_Page2.checked() = false
4. switch back to Page 2 (or already at Page 1)
5. ToggleButton_Page2.checked() = true   //it should be false

### SOURCE:

[Example Source Code](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~aucha/ViewPagerStyle1Toggle.zip)

Answer (score 1):

> So how can I access the ToggleButtons inside a Fragment that is not
>   visible at the moment nor is a neighbor of the current Fragment ? Is
>   there any workaround?

You have a lot of problems in your code, you should read a bit more about `Fragments` and using them in a `ViewPager`.

In the reset and status buttons `OnClickListeners` listeners you write `_adapter.getItem(x);` in an attempt to get a handle to the `Fragment` representing the page at that position. This will not work as simply calling that method will return a **new instance** of the `Fragment` at that position and not the actual `Fragment` the `ViewPager` used(by calling `getItem()` at previous moment). That new instance you get after calling `getItem()` is not tied to the `Activity` and its `onCreateView` method wasn't called so it has no view(and you get the `NullPointerException` when you access it). You then tried to get around this by making the `ToggelButton` as a static field in the `Fragment` which will work as the field will be initialized when the `ViewPager` properly creates the `Fragments` at start. But you shouldn't do this, static fields that hold references to the `Context`(like any `View` does) are dangerous as you risk leaking that `Context`.

Also, related to what I said above, you don't need to pass a `Context` to a `Fragment` as a `Fragment` which is tied to an `Activity` has the `getActivity()` method which returns a reference to that `Activity`.

You shouldn't access any fragments from the `ViewPager` which aren't near to the visible fragment(one on the left/right of the visible position, unless you don't play with the `setOffscreenPageLimit()` method of the `ViewPager`). The `ViewPager` has a mechanism to improve performance(like a `ListView` does) so it only creates what it needs immediately so it can provide a smooth swipe for the user.

I've made some changes to your project, [check them out](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/95923721/ViewPagerStyle1.7z). For further questions please post the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Salut,
Thank you for your good information, and the improved code!

> "But you shouldn't do this, static fields that hold references to the
>   Context(like any View does) are dangerous as you risk leaking that
>   Context."

I'm new to Fragment implementation, and spent hours of finding out how the input String is correctly used for findFragmentByTag().(Now knowing how to use it I never thought that it would be that complex). So I decided to do that static workaround, which wasn't a good idea...

As I understand you, i CAN access more then +-1 Fragments, for example if I use setOffscreenPageLimit(3). I think this is the answer to my question.

Comment: In your particular case you can use `setOffScreenPageLimit()` as the number of fragments is small. But that method should be used carefully as increasing the kept pages will increase the memory consumption. Also, you need `setOffscreenPageLimit(2)`, there would be only 2 pages at any moment on the left/right of the visible visible, not 3 like you set.